# Jquery draggable disable list item after being dropped in other div

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I want if any list item (li) is dragged from products div and drop in cart div , that li will be disabled and user can not able to add it again in cart div.

```
jQuery("#product li").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone"
});

jQuery("#cart ol").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
        $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can **disable the draggable** property As

```
$( "#cart li").draggable({disabled:true});
```

Comment: I just want to disable that particular li not all the items?

Comment: @user3243439  Fort that you need to show your code ..how can write your selector without knowing the DOM positions

Comment: what is the cart div id ??

Comment: try above edit ... just let me know if it gives any error like `cannot disable the property before applying to it ` something like that

Answer (score 0):

In your drop function add:

```
ul.dragged.draggable({disabled:true});
```